Prop types are the same but React Component still has error in Typescript
I've trying to transition from JS to TS and have been trying to type one of my components for a few days now. I figured out most of my errors but this one is still unknown:
I have a component ToastsList.tsx and call the Toast.tsx component as follows:
{toasts?.length > 0 &&
        toasts.map((toast) => (
          <Toast
            title={toast.title}
            id={toast.id}
            message={toast.message}
            type={toast.type}
            hasButton={toast.hasButton}
            buttonMessage={toast.buttonMessage}
            handleButtonClick={toast.handleButtonClick}
            dismissOnButtonClick={toast.dismissOnButtonClick}
            hasUrl={toast.hasUrl}
            url={toast.url}
            urlMsg={toast.urlMsg}
          />
        ))}

When I hover over each property and the value I'm passing it, they all match. But there is a red line under the "Toast" (as in the name of the component I'm rendering) which says:
Type '{ title: string; id: number; message: string; type: string; hasButton: true | undefined; buttonMessage: string | undefined; handleButtonClick: (() => void) | undefined; dismissOnButtonClick: boolean | undefined; hasUrl: boolean | undefined; url: string | undefined; urlMsg: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ToastInfo'.
  
Type '{ title: string; id: number; message: string; type: string; hasButton: true | undefined; buttonMessage: string | undefined; handleButtonClick: (() => void) | undefined; dismissOnButtonClick: boolean | undefined; hasUrl: boolean | undefined; url: string | undefined; urlMsg: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'ToastWithoutButton'.
    Types of property 'hasButton' are incompatible.
      Type 'true | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
        Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

The toasts array comes from a context which contains the same type as Toast requires:
Toast.tsx:
function Toast({
  title,
  message,
  type,
  id,
  hasUrl,
  url,
  urlMsg,
  hasButton,
  buttonMessage,
  handleButtonClick,
  dismissOnButtonClick,
}: ToastInfo) 

Context:
setToasts((toasts) => {
      return [
        ...toasts,
        {
          title,
          type,
          message,
          url,
          urlMsg,
          createdAt: curMilliseconds,
          id: curMilliseconds,
          hasButton,
          buttonMessage,
          handleButtonClick,
          dismissOnButtonClick,
        },
      ].slice(0, MAX_TOASTS_AMOUNT) as ToastInfo[];
    });

Types:
interface BasicToast {
  title: string;
  message: string;
  type: string;
  id: number;
}

interface ToastWithButton {
  hasButton: true;
  buttonMessage: string;
  handleButtonClick: () => void;
  dismissOnButtonClick: boolean;
}

interface ToastWithoutButton {
  hasButton?: never;
  buttonMessage?: never;
  handleButtonClick?: never;
  dismissOnButtonClick?: never;
}

interface ToastWithURL {
  hasUrl: true;
  url: string;
  urlMsg: string;
}

interface ToastWithoutURL {
  // It might be that hasUrl: false or hasUrl: true is always false when compared to boolean
  hasUrl?: false;
  url?: never;
  urlMsg?: never;
}
export type PreIdToastInfo = PreIdBasicToast &
  (ToastWithButton | ToastWithoutButton) &
  (ToastWithURL | ToastWithoutURL);

I tried changing the type definitions but I don't think that's where the issue lies.

That error message is telling you that ToastWithButton and ToastWithoutButton have incompatible types for the hasButton property. Even if you fix it you will run into a similar problem with your With/Without URL variants. Typescript is structurally typed, meaning that you can't really guarantee the absence of a property from a type the way you are trying to. I'd get rid of the "Without" variants entirely.

Thank you @JaredSmith! So is there no way to say, if "hasButton" then the types must have "buttonMessage", "handleMessageClick" . . . but otherwise they should not contain any of those properties. I have a function in Toasts.tsx that handles a button click and I'm trying to use hasButton === true to say, if has button then it has handleButtonClick.
Looking at the design now though, it'll probably be better to pass a children prop with whatever component I need instead; just wondering out of curiosity.

You can (and AFAICT already did) structure the types so that hasButton: true means that the props are guaranteed to have "buttonMessage", "handleMessageClick", but you cannot structure them so that hasButton: false guarantees their absence. If you just remove the "Without" variants everything should just work.
